# PHP Variable Value Change Using IF

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, scope

I am having an issue with my variables value after the IF function. I am looking to change the value of the variable depending on the outcome value of $answer1 on the sender page. However, when I print $answer1 after the IF process, the value has not changed. Before IF it is 5, after the IF process, the Print still produces a 5.

Please can someone advise me how I can increment/decrement using the IF function and affect the value of $answer1 afterwards.

Thank you.

```
<?php
    $finalvalue=5;

    $answer1=$_GET['answer1'];

    if ($answer1=="1"){$finalvalue+2;}
    elseif ($answer1=="2"){$finalvalue+1;}
    elseif ($answer1=="3"){$finalvalue-1;}
    elseif ($answer1=="4"){$finalvalue-2;};
    print "$finalvalue"
?>
```

Comment: are you looking for somthing like `$finalvalue=$finalvalue+2;` and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not properly updating the `$finalvalue`. It should be as follows -

```
<?php
$finalvalue=5;

$answer1=$_GET['answer1'];

if ($answer1=="1"){ $finalvalue = $finalvalue+2;}
elseif ($answer1=="2"){ $finalvalue =  $finalvalue+1;}
elseif ($answer1=="3"){$finalvalue =  $finalvalue-1;}
elseif ($answer1=="4"){$finalvalue =  $finalvalue-2;};
echo $finalvalue;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this has worked, I did try something similar to this earlier however I used the ++ function and I am not sure I coded it correctly!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Thank you for your help earlier Chandan, I have encountered one issue with it though, on application, the last three increments of the final "else if" function have not been affecting the value or $finalvalue, is there something I should be adding to the end of my string for them to take effect? or should I be using pre incrementation as opposed to post incrementation? Please see below. thanks.

Comment: $answer5=$_GET['answer5'];

if ($answer5=="17"){ $finalvalue = $finalvalue+2;}
elseif ($answer1=="18"){ $finalvalue = $finalvalue+1;}
elseif ($answer1=="19"){$finalvalue = $finalvalue-1;}
elseif ($answer1=="20"){$finalvalue = $finalvalue-2;};


print "$finalvalue";

Comment: this should work. Can you confirm by putting `echo` statements in those `elseif` block if it is getting called ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to increment on the variable. Have a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) and try the following:

```
$finalvalue = 5;

$answer1 = $_GET['answer1'];

if ($answer1 == "1") {
    $finalvalue += 2;
} elseif ($answer1 == "2") {
    $finalvalue++;
} elseif ($answer1 == "3") {
    $finalvalue--;
} elseif ($answer1 == "4") {
    $finalvalue -= 2;
}
echo $finalvalue;
```